# Is my answer right? If f is continuous at a and g is discontinuous at a, prove that f+g is discontinuous at a

Tags: calculus, continuity

Okay so I started by setting this hypothesis:
$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a) \land \lim_{x\to a} g(x) \not= g(a)$

Then:

$\lim_{x\to a} g(x) \not= g(a) \implies 
f(a) + \lim_{x\to a} g(x) \not= f(a) + g(a)\implies \lim_{x\to a} f(x) + \lim_{x\to a} g(x) \not= f(a) + g(a) \implies \lim_{x\to a} f+g(x) \not= f+g(a) \implies$ f+g is discontinuous at a

Does that make sense? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The only problem you have is that if $g$ is discontinuous at $a$ then $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ needn't actually exist at all. This is a common annoyance when negating statements of the form $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=L$.

Comment: Hint: use that the sum (or difference) of two continuos functions is itself continuous.

Comment: Okay I’ve tried it but i can’t figure it out, sorry. Can you help me with a foolproof answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove by contradiction. If $f+g$ is continuous at $a$ , then $g=(f+g)-f$, is continuous at $a$ because $f+g$ and $f$ are continuous at $a$, a contradiction!

Comment: That’s neat! Thanks a lot.